# String split by spaces

Tags: java, regex, string, split, space

I know this question has been asked many many times but I don't know why mine is not working.
I have a String like this:

```
String line = "_9________+_10__" // ("_" is a white space)
```

and I did

```
String[] token = line.split("\\s+");
```

When I print the elements in token, the out put is like this:

```
_ //(spaces here)
9
+
10
```

I can't figure out why there's still spaces there... Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Works for me. `System.out.println(Arrays.toString("9        + 10  ".split("\\s+")));` prints `[9, +, 10]`. No extra spaces found.

Comment: @Andreas Do you have a lot of spaces in between "9" and "10"?

Comment: Even if it didn't split the spaces, there's no reason whatsoever to have only 1 occurrence at index 0. Maybe something else in your code?

Comment: Is there a possibility that something is wrong with my RegEx module?

Comment: @HanmingZeng I do. SO collapsed them.

Comment: @HanmingZeng Extremely doubtful. Instead, you should follow this guideline: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way we can do exactly what you do, or you find your error while setting it up.

Comment: @Andreas My bad "9_+ ____10" works. But "_9____+_10" doesn't work.

Comment: @Mariano Sorry. "9_+ ____10" works. But "_9____+_10" doesn't work.

Comment: Your newly updated question has a space at the beginning. `split()` will by default eliminate any *trailing* empty values, but will not eliminate embedded or leading empty values. And your question is wrong: The first value in the token array is **empty**, not a list of spaces. This is as designed, and documented. You should read the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29. It says *"Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array."*

Comment: All right, thank you @Andreas. But is there a way to fix this edge case?

Comment: Have you looked into stringbuffer, that will solve your problem

Comment: @HanmingZeng Yes, two ways: Trim the string before calling `split()`, or ignore the empty value in the array.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you so much. Trim works! Seems like trim will only trim the starting and ending spaces. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is `trim()` and then `split()` it.

```
Srting line = " 9    + 10 ".trim();

String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas Thank you for your help. This problem is now solved.

I will quote Andreas' comment here:
Your newly updated question has a space at the beginning. split() will by default eliminate any trailing empty values, but will not eliminate embedded or leading empty values. And your question is wrong: The first value in the token array is empty, not a list of spaces. This is as designed, and documented. You should read the javadoc: docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/…. It says "Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array."

Two ways to solve this: Trim the string before calling split(), or ignore the empty value in the array.